# How to create two 2x2 images side by side

Tags: floats

I want to place 2 2x2 images side by side.

```
| image1 | image2 |          | image5 | image6 |
 -------- --------             -------  -------
| image3 | image4 |          | image7 | image8 |
 -------- --------             -------  -------
   label:class1                  label:class2
            
             Fig: image dataset
```

This is the code I have written. I am not able to place the class2 label images to the right of the class1 label images.

```
 \begin{figure}
\begin{minipage}[t][6cm]{0.3\linewidth}

{\includegraphics[width=3cm,height=3cm]{img}}
\hspace{0.1 cm}
{\includegraphics[width=3cm,height=3cm]{img}}
\vspace{0.1 cm}
\end{minipage}%

\begin{minipage}[t][6cm]{0.3\linewidth}

{\includegraphics[width=3cm,height=3cm]{img}}
\hspace{0.1 cm}
{\includegraphics[width=3cm,height=3cm]{img}}
\vspace{0.1 cm}
\end{minipage}%


\begin{minipage}[t][6cm]{0.3\linewidth}
{\includegraphics[width=3cm,height=3cm]{img}}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[t][6cm]{0.3\linewidth}
{\includegraphics[width=3cm,height=3cm]{img}}
\end{minipage}

\begin{minipage}[t][6cm]{0.3\linewidth}
    {\includegraphics[width=3cm,height=3cm]{img}}
    \end{minipage}%
    \begin{minipage}[t][6cm]{0.3\linewidth}
    {\includegraphics[width=3cm,height=3cm]{img}}
    \end{minipage}


\caption{Many figures}\label{foo}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/134805), instead of a code snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to TeX:SE!

Like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[ht]
    \setkeys{Gin}{width=3cm,height=3cm}
    \centering
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.48\linewidth}
    \centering
\includegraphics{img}
\hfil
\includegraphics{img}

\medskip
\includegraphics{img}
\hfil
\includegraphics{img}
    \caption{class 1}
\end{subfigure}%
\hfil
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.48\linewidth}
    \centering
\includegraphics{img}
\hfil
\includegraphics{img}

\medskip
\includegraphics{img}
\hfil
\includegraphics{img}
    \caption{class 2}
\end{subfigure}%
\caption{Many figures}
\label{foo}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(red lines indicate document page layout)